# Why does this regexp — which attempts to match characters between “@” characters — fail?

Tags: macos, regex, grep, perl

I need to extract the second field of selected lines in a GEDCOM file. These lines are all of the following format:

```
% grep @ /tmp/XYZ | tail -5
0 @X701@ OBJE
0 @X702@ OBJE
0 @X750@ OBJE
0 @X765@ OBJE
0 @X766@ OBJE
```

But in the following,

```
% egrep "0 \@[^@]\@" /tmp/XYZ
% perl -CSD -p -i -e 's:0 @([^@])@ .*:ZYX \1:g;' /tmp/XYZ
```

the first finds nothing and the second changes nothing;
I don't understand why.

The `CSD` is because although the file is mostly ASCII, it contains some French, Polish, and Chinese, and is encoded UTF-8.

As far as I am aware, `@` is not a special character for regular expressions.

**Update**: I am looking for the field that has the function of a primary key.  It is always delimited by `@` and therefore cannot contain an `@`.  Some lines might reference such a key, but it is only primary when the line starts with `0` .  I must *not* match lines that contain other `@` but that should be ensured by putting in a string-begin `^`.  I must also *not* hit on lines of other formats—I used grep to show the format of the target lines, and tail to limit the size to less than five thousand.

Comment: the [^@] looks wrong in a few ways. first the multiplicity looks wrong (1 char), and the @ is not escaped. I'd suggest you use a alphanumeric pattern there, rather than a "not @".

Comment: If it isn’t a special character, why would it need to be escaped?  And what would be an alphanumeric pattern meaning “any character in Unicode that’s not ‘@‘“?

Comment: (1) The first half of Frank Thomas’s comment is right. `[^@]` will match `X` or `7`. To match `X701`, you need `[^@]*` or `[^@]+`.  (2) `[^@]*` or `[^@]+` should work. But Frank is suggesting that you use something like `[A-Z0-9]+` instead. If you have non-alphanumeric characters between the `@` signs in your file, it would help if you showed some.  (3) No, `@` is not a special character for regular expressions — so why are you escaping it?

Comment: I added the escapes in the egrep because the perl didn't work without them.  I see that the lack of the `+` is my biggest mistake.  But there were others.  From the above, along with an answer that has been deleted, I got it to work with `sed 's/^0 @\(.*\)@ .*/\1 XQX/' /Library/WebServer/Documents/UG/data/HHH.ged | grep XQX | awk '{print $1}'`. I could explain that in an answer, but the deleted answer was almost right.  Perhaps he'll want to put in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you might have lines that look like

   ```
   60 @FOO@ blah
   ```

   or

   ```
   42.0 @记鬼四七@ quux
   ```

   (and you don’t want to match them),
   you should begin your regex with a `^`; e.g., `^0 @…`.
2. `[^@]` will match `X` or `7`. 
   To match any number of non-`@` characters (e.g., `X701`)
   between the two `@` characters, you need `[^@]*` or `[^@]+`; e.g.,

   ```
   % egrep '^0 @[^@]*@' /tmp/XYZ
   % perl -CSD -p -i -e 's:^0 @([^@]*)@ .*:ZYX \1:g;' /tmp/XYZ
   ```

   Use `+` if you must have at least one non-`@` character
   between the two `@` characters. 
   Don’t use `\@` unless plain `@` fails.
3. To avoid matching lines that have a third `@`, use another `[^@]*`
   to specify that the rest of the line is characters other than `@`.

   ```
   % egrep '^0 @[^@]*@ [^@]*$' /tmp/XYZ
   ```